# Count of items from two tables - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

How do I count of items from two tables.
I have country table:

```
 country   |  province 
-----------+--------------
 US        | MA
 US        | FL
 XXXXXX    | XXXXXX
```

and I have city table:

```
 city      |  province  
-----------+--------------
 Boston    | MA
 Worcester | MA
 XXXXXX    | XXXXXX
```

How do I get:

```
country | province | count_of_city_in_each_province
--------+----------+-----------------------------------
US      | MA       | 2
US      | FL       | 0
XXXXXXX | XXXXXXXX | X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join` and `count()` aggregation

```
select country,c.province, count(city)
from country c left join city c1 on c.province=c1.province
group by country,c.province
```